# How to create fixed tabs with ViewPagerIndicator library?

Tags: android

I want to create some tabs with viewpagerindicator library, but the style of this tabs is like the Play Store tabs. (not fixed) and I would want to create fixed tabs. I think I will have to override the TitlePageIndicator but I don't know how can I do it...

To explain it clearly:
[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM1Nd.png)   --->   [What I want](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ic128vMO4Pg/URDQPrOQomI/AAAAAAAABDk/aWeRPSZDMsk/s1600/device-2013-02-05-144612.png)

My viewpager xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
       android:id="@+id/titles_pageindicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    style="@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you exactly need is explained in a simple way here with code & example [Try This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)!